# How to throttle CPU on a Mac?

Tags: macos, cpu, macbook

Device: MBP 2015

I want to throttle CPU so that I can extend the battery life on a single charge.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to different SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/353296/how-to-throttle-cpu-on-a-mac

Comment: Given that the menus change between versions, it’s much harder for anybody to give you an answer that will work for you  if you don’t tell us ***what version of macOS you are running**.*

Comment: mojave is the standart is'nt it @Scott

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297330/force-low-power-mode-on-mac for answers

Comment: Mojave (version 10.14) is the ***current*** release. Version 10.11 was released in 2015, so your 2015 machine could be running something as old as version 10.10, for all I know.

Comment: 10.14.2 .......

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-processor-speed-macbook-pro-43635.html

Quoting:

1. Click on the "Battery Status" icon in the menu bar. Choose "Energy Saver Preferences" to open the System Preferences pane of the same name.
2. Set the "Settings For" drop-down menu at the top of the Energy Saver preference pane to "Battery." Set the "Optimization" drop-down menu to "Better Energy Savings." Press "Command-Q," click on the red Close button at the top of the preference pane or choose "Quit System Preferences" from the System Preferences menu to close the preference pane and save your settings.
3. Click on the "Battery Status" icon in the menu bar. You'll see "Better Energy Savings" as the selected performance parameter. You may notice a slight reduction in system performance as your MacBook Pro reduces processor speed and power usage to conserve battery life.

Comment: That article is +5 years old. There are no such settings right now.

Comment: @user3722246 it would be good, then, to indicate what research you've already done so that answers like this don't get posted.  Besides, apple.SE is almost certainly a better venue.